# c# and LINQ- group objects based on their IDs and then find common values in them

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object collection like in the following.

```
  List<Product> productList=new List<Product>();
```

Structure of the class **Product** is like in the following.

```
   public class Product
   {
       public  int Id;
       public Product(int id)
       {
          Id=id;

       }

       public List<SomeOtherList> t;
  }
```

The class **Product** contains some other list

```
    public class SomeOtherList 
    {
        private int value;

        public  SomeOtherList(int val)
        {
            value=val;

       }


   }
        Product prodOne=new Product(1);
        List<SomeOtherList> temp_1=new List<SomeOtherList>();
        temp_1.Add(new SomeOtherList(10));
       temp_1.Add(new SomeOtherList(20));
       temp_1.Add(new SomeOtherList(30));
       prodOne.t=temp_1;

       Product prodTwo=new Product(2);
       List<SomeOtherList> temp_2=new List<SomeOtherList>();
       temp_2.Add(new SomeOtherList(100));
       temp_2.Add(new SomeOtherList(40));
       temp_2.Add(new SomeOtherList(30));
       prodTwo.t=temp_2;


       Product prodThree=new Product(1);
       List<SomeOtherList> temp_3=new List<SomeOtherList>();
       temp_3.Add(new SomeOtherList(10));
       temp_3.Add(new SomeOtherList(20));

       prodThree.t=temp_3;



      productList.Add(prodOne);
      productList.Add(prodTwo);
      productList.Add(prodThree);
```

I want to get "SomeOtherList" objects common to all the Products. For example, for Product Id 1, I should get SomeOtherList object 20 as the common One.

I have written the following LINQ query to achieve this.

```
   List<Product> t=productList
                          .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
                          .Where(g => g.Count() == productList.Count)
                          .Select(x => x.First())
                          .ToList();
```

But it does not give me what I want . Can someone point what is wrong with that query ?

Comment: Haven't taken a look at the query itself, but 20 isn't common among all of the Products in the code above and p.Id isn't a member of the class - it only has scope in the constructor, so this shouldn't even compile.

Comment: 20 is common to products of which the Id is 1

Comment: @nidarshanifernando - But `10` is also common for Id 1. What about that?

Comment: Isn't intersect method what you are looking for. You could present it as follows

 IEnumerable<SomeOtherList> commonSoOtList = productList.First().t;
 productList.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(p => commonSoOtList = commonSoOtList.Intersect(p.t));    This should give u a all the SomeOtherList

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the *[intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Intersections)* between your `SomeOtherList` when the product is some specific value (i.e. 1).

So you need to first select the each `Product` which has the correct `Id` and then join their `SomeOtherList` together and group by the value.

To do this we need to *flattern* the each `SomeOtherList` for a `Product`, which we can do with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

---

### Single Id

If we are only intrested in a single Id then we can do the following

```
var common1 = productList
    .Where(product => product.Id == 1)
    .SelectMany(product => product.t)
    .GroupBy(groupValue => groupValue.value)
    .Where(groupValue => groupValue.Count() > 1)
    .Select(values => values.First());
```

This will:

1. Filter the products based on Id being equal to 1
2. Flattern each products `SomeOtherList` into one IEnumerable
3. Group each element based on `SomeOtherList.value`
4. Filter out any groups which only have 1 entry, as we only want those that are common

---

### All Id's

If, however, we would like to get the list of all duplicates for each key then we can do the same as for a Single Id but have a first step where we group based on the Id.

```
var common = productList
    .GroupBy(groupId => groupId.Id)
    .Select(groupId => groupId.SelectMany(product => product.t)
        .GroupBy(groupValue => groupValue.value)
        .Where(groupValue => groupValue.Count() > 1)
        .Select(values => values.First().value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to do in single LINQ query, but following code should work.

```
var min = productList.Min(x=>x.Id);
var max = productList.Max(x=>x.Id);

for(int i = min; i<=max;i++)
{
    var products = productList.Where(x=>x.Id = i).ToList();
    List<SomeOtherList> cList = new List<SomeOtherList>();
    foreach(var product in products)
    {
        cList.AddRange(product.t);
    }
    var distinctList = cList.Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nested lists you need to group unwrap the list of SomeOtherList using SelectMany before grouping again. I *think* this is what you're after.

```
var result = productList
    .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
    .Select(pg =>
        new
        {
            Id = pg.Key,
            CommonOtherList = pg
                .SelectMany(solg => solg.t)
                .GroupBy(solg => solg.value)
                .Where(solg => solg.Count() == pg.Count())
                .Select(solg => new { OtherId = solg.Key })
        });

foreach (var product in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(product.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("**Common**");
    foreach (var otherProduct in product.CommonOtherList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-->{0}", otherProduct.OtherId);
    }
}
```